# Current cateogry in wordpress category menu

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, categories

I have a little script that display any categories that contain posts and displays them (like a little menu)

```
<?php 
  $categories = get_categories( array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order'   => 'ASC'
  ) );
  echo '<a class="blog-panel-cat-menu bg-color-1" href="' . get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) . '">All</a>';
  foreach( $categories as $category ) {
      if ($category->count > 0){
        $category_link = sprintf( 
            '<a class="blog-panel-cat-menu bg-color-1" href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
            esc_html( $category->name )
        );
        echo $category_link;
      }
  } 
?>
```

When clicking on any link it will redirect to a page that show the posts for that category eg `mywebsite/news/category/blog/` or `mywebsite/news/category/news/` (`mywebsite/news` being the blog homepage which displays all categories)

When I'm on `mywebsite/news/category/blog/` I want the "blog" link in the menu to have the class `blog-cat-focus` after the current class in the foreach loop like this `<a class="blog-panel-cat-menu bg-color-1 blog-cat-focus" href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Added two more lines to check current category.

```
<?php 
  $categories = get_categories( array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order'   => 'ASC'
  ) );
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
  echo $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
  echo '<a class="blog-panel-cat-menu bg-color-1" href="' . get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) . '">All</a>';
  foreach( $categories as $category ) {
      if ($category->count > 0){
          $cust_class = '';
          if($category->term_id==$cat_id){$cust_class = 'blog-cat-focus';}
        $category_link = sprintf( 
            '<a class="blog-panel-cat-menu bg-color-1 %4$s>" href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
            esc_html( $category->name ),
            $cust_class

        );
        echo $category_link;
      }
  } 
?>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!